# Android how to get tomorrow's date

Tags: java, android, calendar

In my android application. I need to display tomorrow's date, for example today is 5th March so I need to display as 6 March. I know the code for getting today's date, month and year.

date calculating

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    yearat = gc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    yearstr = Integer.toString(yearat);
    monthat = gc.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    monthstr = Integer.toString(monthat);
    dayat = gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    daystr = Integer.toString(dayat);
```

If I have the code

```
dayat = gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1;
```

will it display tomorrow's date. or just add one to today's date? For example, if today is January 31. With the above code, will it display like 1 or 32? If it displays 32, what change I need to make?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

1. Get today's date as a `Calendar`.
2. Add 1 day to it.
3. Format for display purposes.

For example,

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
// now do something with the calendar
```

Comment: Lalto let me ask one thing ... how to get tomorrows month. like

Comment: From the calendar object set to tomorrow, `get` the `MONTH` field value.

Answer (score 60):

Use the following code to display tomorrow date

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = calendar.getTime();

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
```

Use SimpleDateFormat to format the Date as a String:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

String todayAsString = dateFormat.format(today);
String tomorrowAsString = dateFormat.format(tomorrow);

System.out.println(todayAsString);
System.out.println(tomorrowAsString);
```

Prints:

```
05-Mar-2014
06-Mar-2014
```

Comment: use DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", java.util.Locale.getDefault()); to remove warning

Comment: This answer is perfect

Answer (score 8):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = calendar.getTime();

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 5):

you have to add just 1 in your Calendar Day.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Comment: Does it compile? (Thanks for copying my brainfart :)

Comment: @laalto Not Copying you. Just generally think that tomorrow is after one day. So try to give answer that's way. BTW your description is much better. So no worry for that. I know you have a good and best brainfart Thanks anywhy!!

Answer (score 4):

`java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` are terrible to work with. I suggest you use JodaTime which has a much cleaner / nicer API. JodaTime is pretty standard these days.

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Why_Joda-Time

Note that JDK 8 will introduce a new date/time API heavily influenced by JodaTime.

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/introducing-new-date-and-time
- https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310

Comment: Still wondering when Java 8 will finally come to Android phones.

Answer (score 4):

Other options:

```
Calendar tomorrow = Calendar.getInstance();
tomorrow.roll(Calendar.DATE, true);
```

or

```
tomorrow.roll(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

`roll` can also be used to go back in time by passing a negative number, so for example:

```
Calendar yesterday = Calendar.getInstance();
yesterday.roll(Calendar.DATE, -1);
```

Comment: what is the last date of month select?

Answer (score 3):

the first answers pretty much covers the possibilities.
but here one another solution which you can use from org.apache.commons.lang.time:

```
Date lTomorrow = DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in bundled with [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8).

Some example code using the Joda-Time 2.3 library.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime tomorrow = now.plusDays( 1 );
String output = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "FF" ).withLocale(Locale.FRANCE).print( tomorrow );
```

Answer (score 1):

Get todays date by using calendar and then add 1 day to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is working to me well!!

```
    Date currentDate = new Date();// get the current date
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);//add one day to the current date
    dateView.setText(currentDate.toString().substring(0, 10));// put the string in specific format in my textView
```

good luck!!

Comment: add description to your answer

Answer (score 1):

much easier now

```
String today = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd"));

String tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
dayat = gc.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Comment: It doesn't compile and doesn't really help, either.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDate.now()
                   .plusDays( 1 )
```

## java.time

All the other Answers are outmoded, using the troublesome old `Date` & `Calendar` classes or the Joda-Time project which is now in maintenance mode. The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

From that `LocalDate` you can do math to get the following day.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

### Strings

To generate a String representing the `LocalDate` object’s value, call `toString` for text formatted per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard: `YYYY-MM-DD`.

To generate strings in other formats, search Stack Overflow for [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Best way for setting next day is

```
 public void NextDate()
{

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    e_date.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based, just add 1
            .append(mDay+1).append("-").append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mYear).append(" "));



}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just call this method and send date from which you want next date     

public String nextDate(Date dateClicked) {
           // 
String next_day;
calander_view.setCurrentDayTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white_color));
            //calander_view.setCurrentDayBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_color));
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatForDisplaying = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String date_format = dateFormatForDisplaying.format(dateClicked);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("E"); // the day of the week abbreviated
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            try {
                Date date = dateFormatForDisplaying.parse(date_format);
                calendar.setTime(date);
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                String nex = dateFormatForDisplaying.format(calendar.getTime());
                Date d1 = dateFormatForDisplaying.parse(nex);
                String day_1 = simpleDateformat.format(d1);
                next_day = nex + ", " + day_1;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return next_day;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String  lastDate="5/28/2018";
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] sDate=lastDate.split("/");
        calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(sDate[2]),Integer.parseInt(sDate[0]),Integer.parseInt(sDate[1]));

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

//        String todayAsString = dateFormat.format(today);

        for (int i=1;i<29;i++)
        {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
//            td[i].setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
          System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));  
        }
```